# Difference between padding-left and left property CSS

Tags: css, padding

What are the differences between padding-left and left property in CSS ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference

Comment: This is a classical **try it and see** or **google it in seconds** style question.

Comment: The downvotes are because the question doesn't show any effort to find the answer yourself before posting it here.

Comment: This question is now the first result on google for my search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`padding-left` creates padding on the left side of an object's box.  This is space that appears inside the box, causing the overall width of the element to increase.

`left` is used to position an element, where the value given moves the element from its left edge.  This is usually used in conjunction with the `positioning` rule.

Answer (score 1):

**`padding-left`** - defines padding of inner elements

**`left`** - defines position of that element